# Mongoose Schema in NodeJS TypeError: Schema is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, typeerror, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to build a MEAN Stack application for university and I'm pretty new to that stuff. I did a tutorial on how to implement login and registration. Currently, npm start tells me that New Schema ist not a constructor. I've already looked for an answer but couldn't really finde one. So heres my code:

```
    // imported libraries---------------------
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.schema;
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); //generates our token which is required for 
    logging in

    //Mongoose userScheme --------------------
    var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    //@arg hash: hashes provide security if the db is hacked --> password is 
    hashed
    hash: String,
    salt: String
    });
    /*
    The following setPassword method takes the password and salt to create
   a safe password and a salt which is then synchronized with the the DB
   This method runs with every user login / registration
   */
    userSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');

    };
    // checks if the entered password matches with the password stored in DB (hashed)
   //returns a boolean
   userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password){
    var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
    };

    userSchema.methods.generateJwt = function(){
    var expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate()+7); //token expires seven days after creation

    return jwt.sign({
        _id: this._id,
        email: this.email,
        name: this.name,
        exp : parseInt(expiry.getTime()/1000),

        }, "MY_SECRET"); //todo add this secret to mongo db
    };
```

An here is the error message:

```
> groupup@1.0.0 start /Users/Dominik/IDE/ideaProjects/groupup
> node server.js

/Users/Dominik/IDE/ideaProjects/groupup/SEBA_GroupUp/app_api/models/users.js:20
var userSchema = new Schema({
                 ^

TypeError: Schema is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Dominik/IDE/ideaProjects/groupup/SEBA_GroupUp/app_api/models/users.js:20:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Dominik/IDE/ideaProjects/groupup/SEBA_GroupUp/app_api/models/db.js:53:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I also checked the documentation for mongoose but I to me the type things didn't look bad. 
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using uppercase for schema:

```
//                    v
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
```

instead of

```
var Schema = mongoose.schema;
```

Comment: Thank you @maxpaj! Sometimes the small things crash your code :D